# How to compare groups with different size in R when "Estimated effects may be unbalanced"

Tags: r, anova

I use `aov()` in R to do anova when groups has same size. Otherwise `Estimated effects may be unbalanced`.

1. Is `same sample size` required in anova?(never mentioned in statistics textbook)
2. Which function can be used to compare groups with different size?

Comment: Plenty of relevant results here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=anova+unequal+sample+size

Comment: I recommend the Anova function in the car package for routine use.  You would fit the model with lm and then pass this object to Anova.

Comment: It's better if you don't phrase statistical issues as R questions. Why kind of anova are you doing (ie 1. what's the model? 2. what hypothesis are you testing? Is this just a one way comparison of means?)